# Windows 2008 default system regular font missing/broken

Tags: remote-desktop, fonts, windows-server-2008

My Windows Server 2008 R2 decided to hide/break regular system font. 
Because I'm connecting through RDP my options are limited :/

VPS host/administrator told me to F** off and said they don't maintain windows servers

[image: no fonts]

I thought it's more generic problem but now after opening powershell I confirmed it's only **"regular"** font missing. I see bold font working. See screenshot below

[image: proof that bold font works]

How to fix/change that regular font to something else with powershell? I can't use Explorer at all.

Comment: I'd tell that VPS Provider to do the same and leave them personally; Good luck fixing it!

Comment: Can't you just leave Windows completely and migrate to something sane?

Comment: @djsmiley2k I totally agree, migrating right now but I could use access to server to get some configs (backup from Saturday so it's ok)

Comment: @EugenRieck I wish I could, it's POS software that require Windows to run